# Failing to connect my simulated device to azure IoT hub to send the data using Python

Tags: python, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-hub

Can anybody please tell me why am I getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-215347aec7aa> in <module>()
     11 from iothub_client import IoTHubClient, IoTHubClientError, IoTHubTransportProvider, IoTHubClientResult
     12 from iothub_client import IoTHubMessage, IoTHubMessageDispositionResult, IoTHubError, DeviceMethodReturnValue
---> 13 from iothub_client_args import get_iothub_opt, OptionError
     14 
     15 # HTTP options

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iothub_client_args'
```

When I tried to run [this python script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/device/samples/iothub_client_sample.py)

I have registered my device and replaced the connection string also, 
I have installed 1)azure-iothub-service-client and 2)azure-iothub-device-client packages

Am I missing any packages?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error information, it looks like you lose `iothub_client_args.py` sample file.

You can download this file [iothub_client_args.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/device/samples/iothub_client_args.py) and put it in the same folder with the sample file you were running.

If you have cloned the SDK repository, navigate to the folder device/samples and put the file there.